# Three.js click recognition is happening 4 squares away from object (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I am trying to move the cube by clicking on it, however, the cube does not move unless I click 4 squares above it. This behavior is consistent throughout the scene.

For example, in the image below, I can only click and drag the left-bottom cube by clicking on the 2nd cube 4 spaces above it:

[image: demo image]

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ThreeScene from "./ThreeScene";

function App() {
  const [cubeCount, setCubeCount] = useState(0);
  const [isEditMode, setIsEditMode] = useState(true); // Start in edit mode

  const handleAddCube = () => {
    if (isEditMode) {
      setCubeCount(cubeCount + 1);
    }
  };

  const handleToggleEditMode = () => {
    setIsEditMode(!isEditMode);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Draggable Cube Placer</h2>
      <button onClick={handleToggleEditMode}>
        {isEditMode ? "Lock" : "Edit Mode"}
      </button>
      {isEditMode && <button onClick={handleAddCube}>Add Cube</button>}
      <ThreeScene cubeCount={cubeCount} isEditMode={isEditMode} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ThreeScene.js:

```
    import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";

const ThreeScene = ({ cubeCount, isEditMode }) => {
  const mountRef = useRef(null);
  const cubesRef = useRef([]);
  const sceneRef = useRef(new THREE.Scene());
  const cameraRef = useRef(
    new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    )
  );
  const rendererRef = useRef(new THREE.WebGLRenderer());
  const selectedCubeRef = useRef(null);
  const mouseRef = useRef(new THREE.Vector2());
  const raycasterRef = useRef(new THREE.Raycaster());
  const planeRef = useRef(new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), -0.5));
  const offsetRef = useRef(new THREE.Vector3());
  const controlsRef = useRef(null); // Reference for OrbitControls

  useEffect(() => {
    const controls = new OrbitControls(
      cameraRef.current,
      rendererRef.current.domElement
    );
    controls.enablePan = true;
    controls.enableZoom = true;
    controlsRef.current = controls;
    // Disable controls if in edit mode
    controls.enabled = !isEditMode;

    return () => controls.dispose(); // Cleanup controls on component unmount
  }, [isEditMode]); // Reinitialize controls when isEditMode changes
  useEffect(() => {
    // Adjust camera position and OrbitControls based on edit mode
    if (isEditMode) {
      // Position camera to look from the top when in edit mode
      cameraRef.current.position.set(0, 20, 0);
      cameraRef.current.lookAt(sceneRef.current.position);
      if (controlsRef.current) {
        controlsRef.current.enabled = false;
      }
    } else {
      // Restore camera position when not in edit mode
      cameraRef.current.position.set(0, 5, 10);
      cameraRef.current.lookAt(sceneRef.current.position);
      if (controlsRef.current) {
        controlsRef.current.enabled = true;
      }
    }
    if (controlsRef.current) {
      controlsRef.current.update();
    }
  }, [isEditMode]);

  // Event Handlers
  const onMouseMove = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!selectedCubeRef.current) return;

    mouseRef.current.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouseRef.current.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycasterRef.current.setFromCamera(mouseRef.current, cameraRef.current);

    const intersect = raycasterRef.current.ray.intersectPlane(
      planeRef.current,
      new THREE.Vector3()
    );
    if (intersect) {
      selectedCubeRef.current.position.set(
        intersect.x + offsetRef.current.x,
        selectedCubeRef.current.position.y,
        intersect.z + offsetRef.current.z
      );
    }
  };

  const onMouseDown = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouseRef.current.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouseRef.current.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycasterRef.current.setFromCamera(mouseRef.current, cameraRef.current);

    const intersects = raycasterRef.current.intersectObjects(
      cubesRef.current,
      true
    );
    console.log(intersects);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      selectedCubeRef.current = intersects[0].object;
      selectedCubeRef.current.material.opacity = 0.5;

      console.log("Cube clicked:", selectedCubeRef.current);

      const intersect = raycasterRef.current.ray.intersectPlane(
        planeRef.current,
        new THREE.Vector3()
      );
      if (intersect) {
        offsetRef.current.subVectors(
          selectedCubeRef.current.position,
          intersect
        );
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No cube clicked");
    }
  };

  const onMouseUp = (event) => {
    if (selectedCubeRef.current) {
      selectedCubeRef.current.position.x =
        Math.round(selectedCubeRef.current.position.x / 0.5) * 0.5;
      selectedCubeRef.current.position.z =
        Math.round(selectedCubeRef.current.position.z / 0.5) * 0.5;
      selectedCubeRef.current.material.opacity = 1;
    }
    selectedCubeRef.current = null;
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  };

  // Setup scene, camera, and renderer
  useEffect(() => {
    cameraRef.current.position.set(0, 5, 10);
    rendererRef.current.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    mountRef.current.appendChild(rendererRef.current.domElement);
    sceneRef.current.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      rendererRef.current.render(sceneRef.current, cameraRef.current);
    };

    animate();

    return () => {
      mountRef.current.removeChild(rendererRef.current.domElement);
    };
  }, []);

  // Add or remove cubes when cubeCount changes
  useEffect(() => {
    const updateCubes = () => {
      while (cubesRef.current.length < cubeCount) {
        const cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: 808080,
          transparent: false,
          opacity: 1.0,
          wireframe: false,
        });
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
        cube.position.set(0, 0.5, 0);
        sceneRef.current.add(cube);
        cubesRef.current.push(cube);
      }
    };

    updateCubes();
  }, [cubeCount]);

  //Event Listener
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div ref={mountRef} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }} />;
};

export default ThreeScene;
```

Comment: Try offsetX/Y instead of clientX/Y